# Nslookup resolves server address but gives server can't find SERVFAIL error at the same time

Tags: dns, nslookup

In our office network if I run
`nslookup dl.min.io`
I get a response with both the address and an error:

```
Server:     <server IP>
Address:    <server IP>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   dl.min.io
Address: 178.128.69.202
Name:   dl.min.io
Address: 138.68.11.125
** server can't find dl.min.io: SERVFAIL
```

There is no such error for other domain names.
There is no such error with other DNS servers, like Google's.
I do not control the DNS server, and I think it is a Win2003 server.

What might be the cause of such behavior? How can I debug it further?

Comment: The DNS server you're using might have corrupted its cache, or have some other problem. There might be some more information in the event log of the DNS server, but since you don't control that server, the only thing you *can* do is report the problem to the person or people who do control that server. (Note that the SOA record of `min.io` lists the master server for the domain as `ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com`, and the admin contact as `cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com`, so it looks like the domain is managed by Google.)